# How to build atlassian plugin for quick reload?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I've completed the [atlassian sdk helloworld plugin tutorial](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/set-up-the-atlassian-plugin-sdk-and-build-a-project/create-a-helloworld-plugin-project), and so far I'm happy that atlas-run shows the plugin.

Import to IntelliJ Idea also went clean.

I understand that [Quick Reload plugin](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/developer-tools/automatic-plugin-reinstallation-with-quickreload) is supposed to help avoiding to  run time-expensive `atlas-run` after each minor update.

Could someone please suggest which maven task should be run in order to trigger Quick Reload?

I've tried running: clean, install, deploy from IntelliJ Idea, and each of those crashed Jira.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just run "atlas-package" to trigger quick reload.

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: :) I just realized I can do it using package task in Maven Projects/Lifecycle. It looks equivalent.

Comment: I'm having trouble to use the "Alternate Resource Directories". It seems not to work and so I have to package the plugin every time I change a css or a js :( Any clues?

Comment: Can I automate atlas-package command to be run when I click "build project" ?